# Not able to save/download file on local pc. File is available inside code in byte[]

Tags: c#, sharepoint, filesystems

I am working on SharePoint web application backend c# and hosted on azure.
Basically I working on virtual machine. Using citrix to access pc.

I have file data in format of byte[] array in side code and want to save/download it on local, but I am not able to do that.

For download I used response streams
Example :- Response.output (data) / Response.Binarywrite(data).

This didn't work

Or

To save on local I used desktop path

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Above code return some different location which is not accessible for me.

> Error : D:/Windows/System32 not accessible.

Previously I used above code to access desktop it always work without any error.
But looks like as I am working on virtual machine and application is also hosted on azure that's why it's returning some different path.

Please help me. How I can save/download file on my local?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Core (Or Net 5 or 6)?  The updates for Core in the last few years was to make code run the same on Windows and Linux.  Lots of changes were made.  If you target old Net versions like Net 4.7.2 you will get old behavior.  If looks like your Citrux machine was installed on the D:\ driver.  Normal users d not have write permission to Windows folder.  If you want to write change folder.  When in VS you are not an ADMIN.  To get ADMIN inside VS the right client VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The c# executable will have ADMIN, just inside VS you do not have ADMIN

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replay. I am not using core technology.Its just a dotnet web aplication which using SharePoint frontend.(SharePoint provider hosted app). I can not directly interact with executable files as it's deployed on azure, I need to publish it everytime to check the code is working.

Comment: You do not need to publish every time if you are not changing methods.  You can copy the exe.   Publish basically updates windows dlls on deploy machine to match the build machine.  So make minor changes to exe you just need to copy the exe.  The issue is the code on server needs to be start with correct permission to read/write the folder.If you are running the server code as a service than you should run with a service account and start with an account that has proper permissions.It is not advisable to run a web service with Admin.  Instead place file that need read/write on a network drive.

Comment: Ok. I will try this one and let you know.

Comment: Hello, 

I think this is oncept of interactive logon that there is only c drive in my virtual pc and i don't have access to any folder or file when I try to access it from code wich is hosted on azure. 

Regarding download issue, I am using another site to fetch the data (Cross site interaction) and download it on current site. 

One cookie is bloked in networks response header tab.I am also not sure that this is exact reason for download error but still trying to fix this. 

You can search concept of samesite wich has three types :1) Strict. 2) Lax3) None. 

Thanks

Comment: Use are suing a relay to download file on other site.  You would need to use NTFS to access a non windows drive.